# How to filter/clamp/suppress positive voltage spikes from IC

Tags: filter, noise

I need to work with an IC or more specifically a PCB (RFID reader) that is feeding back positive voltage spikes into my supply line.

What is the generally accepted solution of isolating noisy IC's from feeding back into the supply line? Preferably up to the kHz range.

I read up on Capacitance multipliers, they should work really well with any droops from current draw but not with preventing positive spikes from the load.

Comment: Decoupling caps absorb local impulse currents.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question would be "add sufficient decoupling capacitors": As you know, the current that flows into a capacitor is proportional to the time-derivative of the voltage across it. So, if there is a sudden voltage spike, a capacitor is able to absorb that by storing its energy.

You're not telling us anything about the energy of these spikes, but seeing that this is RFID, they probably won't be too bad: place a 100 nF ceramic cap really close to the IC between supply and ground, and complete with a 1 µF (which can slightly further away – avoid vias between capacitor and IC).

Now, I hear that "capacitance multiplier" method once in a while to tackle insufficiently stable power supplies (i.e. supplies that can't deal with load changes / spikes). To me, that sounds like a "textbook method", introduced by someone who just got access to an early transistor in the 1960s and built something really useful for the time.

A modern LDO (low-dropout regulator) is a device actually built to fulfill exactly the role that your capacitance multiplier is supposed to fulfill: stabilize an output voltage with a limited capacitance. Buy a **modern** LDO (e.g. an LP4907) for a couple of cent: they have excellent noise rejection properties, and come in tiny packages (assuming your RFID reader doesn't need large currents). You can place them close to he IC, so that the trace inductance doesn't become large.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the shortcomings of the capacitance multiplier?

Comment: It's not what you want: you want a stable voltage and high noise suppression. You *can* achieve that with a large capacitance, but a stabilizing voltage regulator is better than that. It's especially better than an expensively and imperfectly "imitated" large capacitance. You're choosing a random solution to a problem to which there are better, cheaper solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Ferrite beads are a good option if the noise is within a relevant range of that device. But at a few kHz most of them are fairly ineffective.

If power draw is very low, resistors with appropriate de-coupling capacitors are great.  Capacitors can absorb most of the transient, but having a high impedance to work against means the cap doesn't have to have amazingly low impedance in the range of interest (at high frequencies that can mean trying to get precisely self-resonant caps).

If the spikes edge rate is fast, you might need a resistor in series with the cap to prevent prevent it from ringing.

Small inductors also work if there are no high-frequency concerns.  You can probably get something that will work for up to an amp in a package as small as 0806 at 4.7uF.

LDOs often have an output to input diode that will pass spikes right along, but that will depend on individual characteristics of that device.